# Bookmarking service with webpage screenshot

Tags: web-apps, screenshot, bookmark

I’m looking for a bookmarking service similar to [Pinboard](https://pinboard.in/), but with screenshots of the webpages.

Key factors I’m looking for:

- Clean/simple UI
- Transparent and reliable founders/dev
- Reasonably priced (not above $5/month)
- Maintained
- Thumbnail or larger screenshot of bookmarked URL

I have checked the following services, but they don't comply with the above:

- Delicious
- Diigo
- Gimmebar
- Google Bookmarks
- Historio.us
- Kippt
- LinkBoard
- Miitla
- Mr. Wong
- Pearltrees
- StashMarks
- Zootool

Comment: Pinboard allows to [export](https://pinboard.in/howto/#export) your bookmarks. Do you require this feature, too? -- What about other features? (for those that don’t know Pinboard, or in case you don’t need all of their features)

Comment: That's obviously a plus, but one cannot be too demanding when the alternatives are so scarce. The same goes for other special features.

Comment: Diigo is really cool, but way too expensive. I'm looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for you,

**[Atavi](http://atavi.com/about)**
Atavi is a free, yet extremely convenient, web service.

Bookmark the websites you need, group them the way you want and sync the bookmarks with any device or browser.

Fine-tune Atavi at your own choice: create bookmark groups, choose the theme that best suits you and set the number of bookmarks to display.
[image: Atavi User Interface]

Comment: It does't cache the webpage? (screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **[Evernote Web Clipper](https://evernote.com/webclipper/)**.

> **Evernote Web Clipper** is a simple extension for your web browser that lets you capture full-page articles, images, selected text, important emails, and any web page that inspires you. Save everything to Evernote and keep it forever. (Taken from [this](https://evernote.com/webclipper/guide/))

This extension is available for current modern browser, like Firefox, IE 7+, Safari, Opera, and Google Chrome. First of all, you must have [Evernote](https://evernote.com) account in order this extension can be worked. All of your saved clip will be saved into your Evernote account and you can view them forever via web application or desktop application that Evernote provides. Answering what you're looking for:

- Clean/Simple UI

  I can say "yes". Look the extension works below:
  [image]
- Transparent and reliable founders/dev

  You can share what you have bookmarked to people who you want to know.
- Reasonably price (not above $5/month)

  I am so sorry, it's above $5/month for plus plan. You can start this service for free, though. Compare about pricing and feautures [here](https://evernote.com/pricing/).
- Maintained

  Yes, because all your bookmarked clip will be stored in Evernote.
- Thumbnail or larger screen shot of bookmarked URL

  I suggest see some examples [here](https://evernote.com/webclipper/guide/).

Currently, I am using this extension to clip/bookmark the page what inspires me. I hope this what you're looking for. Feel free to comment.